# How do I add a sign up page into my Parse app with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Dose anyone know how I can make a user sign up with parse in Swift Xcode 6.4? 
I Have searched everything and can't find one that works.

I Tried this code but it did not work.

It said:

> Use of unresolved identifier PFUser

```
import UIKit

class SignupViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func loginVerifyButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var usrEntered = usernameTextField.text
    var pwdEntered = passwordTextField.text
    var emlEntered = emailTextField.text
    if usrEntered != "" && pwdEntered != "" && emlEntered != "" {
        // If not empty then yay, do something
    } else {
        WrongInfo()
    }
}
func userSignUp() {
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = usrEntered
    user.password = pwdEntered
    user.email = emlEntered
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

func WrongInfo(){
    var WrongInfo:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "ALL FEILDS REQUIRED", message: "Please use all feilds!", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "ok")
}
}
```

Comment: Let me give one comment on how you tried to highlight the code: For code blocks you should use an indent of 4 spaces.
And you should provide more information on what erroneous behaviour yo u get with your code. *What* doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import Parse , in Appdelegate.swift file! if still getting same error import Parse in signup view controller too

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own view and then implement it/segue users to it based on the users current status. If they click your sign up button segue them to a custom view and then act accordingly. You would sign them up with a function similar to what you have offered already in your question:

```
func myMethod() {
var user = PFUser()
user.username = "myUsername"
user.password = "myPassword"
user.email = "email@example.com"
// other fields can be set just like with PFObject
user["phone"] = "415-392-0202"

user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
    // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
  } else {
    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
  }
}
```

You essentially could use the same view you already have since your fields are identical but call different methods depending on the button they select.